# Slurm Job Output File

Tags: slurm, sbatch

I am running multiple jobs trying to have better performance results. To this end, I am generating a UUID and need the file name of the output to include this UUID.

Currently, I am defining the name of the output as follows:
**#SBATCH --output=/PATH/result.txt**

and I am generating the UUID with this command:
**uuid= uuidgen -t**

I need to add the generated uuid to the file name. How to do that?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If your UUID can be non-random, you can just use the Slurm JobID which will be for all practical purposes, unique to the cluster. In that case, you will write

```
#SBATCH --output=/PATH/result-%j.txt
```

Otherwise, you will have to either

- choose the UUID at submission time and run the `sbatch` command like this:

```
sbatch ... --output=/PATH/result-$(uuidgen -t).txt submission_script.slurm
```

- or, redirect the output of the commands you run inside the submission script "by hand" with the `exec` command:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#SBATCH ...
#SBATCH ...
FILE="PATH/result-$(uuidgen -t).txt"
exec > $FILE

...
```